# Why am I unable to approve this edit?

Tags: bug, documentation

Consider [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12918):

Clicking "Approve" results in an error:

[image]

Opening up Chrome's Web Inspector reveals the path (`https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/go/drafts/12767/approve-draft`) is redirecting to the HTTP 500 error page:

[image]

Comment: The edit doesn't appear to actually change anything, so I'd guess the server doesn't know what to do with the edit if you try to approve it.

Comment: @animuson that's a separate bug :P The edit changes the versions but that isn't reflected anywhere in the diff.

Comment: Ah that would explain it. I don't believe the bug is that it's not *displaying* version changes, but that it doesn't record them with the suggestion in the first place.

Comment: @animuson well don't look at me - you have the source code :D